# New to java, Guessing Game project Error

Tags: java

I am currently working on a guessing game project, and I thought I completed it but I get this error when I try to compile it:

> Error: Could not find or load main class guessinggame.

I probably made an obvious mistake but I hope someone can help me. If there is any way to improve or fix this project, please comment. I would love to learn all the possible ways to do this other than the repetitive if statements.

```
package stringvars;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class guessinggame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner mylevela = new Scanner(System.in);
    int level1 = 1;
    int level2 = 2;
    int level3 = 3;
    int level4 = 4;
    int mylevel;
    boolean chooselevel = false;
    while (chooselevel == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the level you want: ");
        mylevel = mylevela.nextInt();
        if(mylevel > 4 && mylevel < 1)
        {
          chooselevel = true;
        }

         if(mylevel == 1)

        {
          Random numberlevel1 = new Random();
          int randnumber1 = numberlevel1.nextInt(10);
          int tries1 = 0;
          Scanner guess1 = new Scanner(System.in);
          int myguess1;
          boolean wingame = false;
            while(wingame == false){
              System.out.println("Pick a number between 1 and 10: ");
              myguess1 = guess1.nextInt();
              tries1++;
              if(myguess1 == randnumber1){
                wingame = true;
              }
             else if(myguess1 > randnumber1){
               System.out.print("Too high, try again");
              }
              else if (myguess1 < randnumber1){
                System.out.print("Too low, try again");
              }
            }
            System.out.print("You win! It took you" + tries1 + "tries.");
          }
      if(mylevel == 2)
      {
        Random numberlevel2 = new Random();
        int randnumber2 = numberlevel2.nextInt(100);
        int tries2 = 0;
        Scanner guess2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myguess2;
        boolean wingame2 = false;
        while(wingame2 == false){
          System.out.println("Pick a number between 1 and 100: ");
          myguess2 = guess2.nextInt();
          tries2++;
          if(myguess2 == randnumber2){
            wingame2 = true;
          }
          else if(myguess2 > randnumber2){
            System.out.print("Too high, try again");
          }
          else if (myguess2 < randnumber2){
            System.out.print("Too low, try again");
          }
        }
        System.out.print("You win! It took you" + tries2 + "tries.");
      }
      if(mylevel == 3)
      {
        Random numberlevel3 = new Random();
        int randnumber3 = numberlevel3.nextInt(1000);
        int tries3 = 0;
        Scanner guess3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myguess3;
        boolean wingame3 = false;
        while(wingame3 == false){
          System.out.println("Pick a number between 1 and 1000: ");
          myguess3 = guess3.nextInt();
          tries3++;
          if(myguess3 == randnumber3){
            wingame3 = true;
          }
          else if(myguess3 > randnumber3){
           System.out.print("Too high, try again");
         }
          else if (myguess3 < randnumber3){
            System.out.print("Too low, try again");
          }
        } 
        System.out.print("You win! It took you" + tries3 + "tries.");
      }
       if(mylevel == 4)
      {
        Random numberlevel4 = new Random();
        int randnumber4 = numberlevel4.nextInt(10000);
        int tries4 = 0;
        Scanner guess4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myguess4;
        boolean wingame4 = false;
        while(wingame4 == false){
         System.out.println("Pick a number between 1 and 10000: ");
          myguess4 = guess4.nextInt();
          tries4++;
          if(myguess4 == randnumber4){
            wingame4 = true;
          }
          else if(myguess4 > randnumber4){
            System.out.print("Too high, try again");
          }
          else if (myguess4 < randnumber4){
            System.out.print("Too low, try again");
          }
        }
        System.out.print("You win! It took you" + tries4 + "tries.");
       }
    }
     System.out.print("Error, enter a level between 1 and 4");
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to compile it?

Comment: What command are you using to compile it?

Comment: i was in Jcreator, but now Im using an online compiler.

Comment: what do you mean by command? Sorry, I'm super new to this.

Comment: @LiamCarroll Which online compiler are you using?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a compiler error but rather a run error. The compiler doesn't look for `main`. So I'm guessing you are trying to run it without the package name, or your online IDE doesn't allow packages.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. He's probably using something like IdeOne, that wants a specific format for the main class

Comment: http://www.compilejava.net/  this one, I was also wondering how I could simplify this project, it seems way too long for such a simple task.

Comment: Advice: download a real IDE to your computer, like Eclipse, Intellij IDEA, NetBeans - and compile and run with that. The online IDEs are very limited. In this case, indeed it doesn't support packages, and it also doesn't seem to give you a console.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you put the main class, `guessinggame`, inside of package `stringvars`. The online compiler you're using, [Compile Java](http://www.compilejava.net/), expects no package declaration at the start of your code to properly compile.So you need to remove the first line, `package stringvars;`.

Beware that even after you compile it, this code isn't going to work: I tried it in the online editor and it gave me a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` on line 17. I think this is caused by the fact that your code expects input from the console while the site doesn't allow you to write it in.